# What does the number for perspective in rotationEffect3d do?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, 3d, projection

I noticed rotation3dEffect had a `perspective` parameter which controls the vanishing point. What I failed to understand was how this number affects the vanishing point. It says the default value is 1.0. What does this mean? 100%? x1 scale? 1 pts? 1.0 what?

I tried predicting what the shape would look like after changing the `perspective` parameter, but since I couldn't figure out what it does I wasn't able to predict the shape.

All I know is the vanishing point seems to come closer the larger this number is, however, the size and distortion of the shape still is unpredictable. I can't tell how the system is drawing the shape using the `perspective` parameter. If someone can explain what this number is and how the system uses it to draw the shape I'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Perhaps there's some multiplication/division going on? If you set the `perspective` parameter to 0.0 the vanishing point is basically an infinite distance away (hence the shape looks normal), which usually happens when you divide by 0. Thus, I'm suspecting the system uses that number to do some sort of multiplication/division.

Answer (score 1):

`perspective` defines the relative vanishing point. The higher the value, the closer the vanishing point is.

In cases like this it always helps me to set up an interactive test like this one:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var rotation = 0.0
    @State private var perspective = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0), anchor: .leading, anchorZ: 0, perspective: perspective)
            
            Text("Rotation: \(rotation, specifier: "%.1f") degrees")
            Slider(value: $rotation, in: -180...180)
            
            Text("Perspective: \(perspective, specifier: "%.1f")")
            Slider(value: $perspective, in: -5...5)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: When I increase the value of `perspective`, the parallel lines converge more. Won't this mean the higher the number the closer the vanishing point? When the `perspective` approaches 0 the parallel lines seem to become straighter (less angular), thus meaning the vanishing point is further off.

Comment: yes you are right.